# Query to remove duplicates based on criteria

Tags: duplicates

We have a table of courses

```
>    EIN       COURSE      DESC       COMPLETE_DATE
>    1234      MOLW2013    xxxxx      2013-09-01
>    1234      MOLW2014    xxxxx      null
>    1234      MOLW2015    xxxxx      null
>    5678      MOLW2013    xxxxx      null
>    5678      MOLW2014    xxxxx      null
>    5678      MOLW2015    xxxxx      2015-08-10
>    9876      MOLW2013    xxxxx      null
>    9876      MOLW2014    xxxxx      null</br>
>    9876      MOLW2015    xxxxx      null</br>
```

We would like to remove rows where an employee has taken the course already, keeping just the valid row with a date completed.
Further, we wish to keep the 2015 course if the employee has never completed the course, but remove the older records.

I appreciate any insight.

Comment: What is the database?  If it's SQL based, something like  DELETE from table_name WHERE complete_date IS NOT NULL

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry, its Oracle.

Comment: The issue here is, we wish to keep one course record, whether completed or not based on the most recent course. So based on the example above for 9876, we would like to keep MOLW2015 only and for 1234, just keep MOLW2013 record.